# Lazy initialization of static fields should be synchronized

Tags: constructor, lazy-initialization

I am initializing a static field in constructor and Sonar indicating "Lazy initialization of static fields should be synchronized".

```
public class Person {
static Set<String> names;
 public Person() {
    names = createSet();// Sonar warning here
  }
}
```

I know we can use synchronize keyword to resolve it in setters. But how to resolve this issue in case of constructor?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Person {
static Set<String> names;
public Person() {
    if (names == null) {
        synchronized (Person.class) {
            if (names == null)
                names = createSet();
        }
    }
}
```

You have to check it twice. Because if two threads enter the outer `if(names == null)` if statement, then the inner check filters that too. This type of checking is called `Double Checked Locking`. Refer [this.](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
public class Person {
static Set<String> names;
public Person() {
    if (names == null) {
        synchronized (Person.class) {
            names = createSet();
        }
    }
}
```

But, to be honest, the construction looks a little bit strange. Why person has static names? I would probably think about changing the architecture.

Answer (score 0):

If the set is initialized once, it is better to do it at the declaration, that's avoid using synchronized, as it degrades the performance. The JVM always initializes fields before any thing.

```
public class Person {
static Set<String> names = createSet();
public Person() {

}
}
```